# simple text toggle that opens just the next p

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I have to say I'm a beginner and my very question could be too obvious to some of you. But please be nice though.
We need a small text toggle based on jquery. It works perfectly so far but it opens every text on a given page. Is there a possibility that it opens just the next "p" and not every "Text2" on the page? Thanks for your help.

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $('.hidden').slideToggle();
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'more' ? 'less' : 'more');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text2</p>

<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text2</p>

<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text2</p>
```

Comment: perhaps give it an unique id? so that you just need to toggle only for that id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to parent *paragraph* then use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target following sibling to get `.hidden` *paragraph*.

```
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('p').next('.hidden').slideToggle();
  $(this).text(function(_, text) {
    return text == 'more' ? 'less' : 'more';
  });
});
```

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('p').next('.hidden').slideToggle();
  $(this).text(function(_, text) {
    return text == 'more' ? 'less' : 'more';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text1</p>

<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text2</p>

<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show">more</a></p>
<p style="display: none;" class="hidden">Text3</p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much.